# How to load AdMob ad on every view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, admob

I am currently loading this code below on every view load.  Is there a more performance direction I can take, like a singleton, or is this the best way to load ads in iOS?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    buttonsView.orientation = CSLinearLayoutViewOrientationVertical;
    buttonsView.verticalAlignment = CSLinearLayoutItemVerticalAlignmentBottom;

    self.ad.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    self.ad.rootViewController = self;
    self.ad.delegate = self;
    self.ad.adSize = GADAdSizeFromNSValue(NSValueFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait));
    [self.ad loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. One method is to create a UIViewController super class. In the viewDidLoad method of the superclass implement the ad code. Any view which needs this ad code should just inherit from the super class and it get's this behavior. If each UIViewController has specific values to identify it as a unique view you can set this values in the before calling [super viewDidLoad] on super class. If this doesn't make any sense let me know and I can put some code together for you.

Another possible approach is to use method swizzling to modify the default behavior of the UIViewController and add your code this way. Just google "method swizzling objective-C". Here's one of the better articles on this that I like: https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/04/16/right-way-to-swizzle/